# Create Tree from multiple tables in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5

I am creating a Tree from two tables:

```
 DOC_RLSE      with column IWR_NO (num), IWR_Desc (char)
 DOC_RLSE_DTL  with column IWR_NO (num), ELM_NAME (char)
```

I have reffered a good Apex application according to which the code is right:
But it still gives me an error that :
 line 11, column 5: ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression (which may have only one reason i.e data type is wrong or order is wrong in UNION but its not the case 
Code is as below:

```
 select case when connect_by_isleaf = 1 then 0
        when level = 1             then 1
        else                           -1
   end as status, 
   level, 
   name as title, 
   null as icon, 
   id as value, 
   null as tooltip,
   null as link
 from (
 SELECT IWR_NO as id,
   null as parent,
   IWR_DESC as name,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   NULL
  FROM DOC_RLSE
 UNION ALL
 SELECT ELM_NAME as id,
   IWR_NO as parent,
   ELM_NAME as name,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   NULL

 FROM DOC_RLSE_DTL
 )
 start with parent is null
 connect by prior id = parent
 order siblings by name;
```

I have tried for single tables and it is working. Could someone please look into this and let me know if there is some mistake.

According to this oracle apex application there is nothing wrong:
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=36648:13:109092209475531:::::
To log in to this sample application, please **use guest / apex_chart_demo**.

Click on link to log in to application and see the working tree

Comment: Change the type of both columns `IWR_NO` to varchar2, (in examples in this [thread](https://community.oracle.com/message/4514158) all similar columns `PROJ_NUM` are varchar).
After this modification your query worked for me, but I don't see your data, so not 100% sure of this solution.

Comment: thanks Ponder Stibbons .. but why can't we keep a parent as Numeric field?
This cannot be that PLSQL dont let us use parent as num ?

Comment: You can't use different types in union, like here: `select 1 from dual union select 'a' from dual` - this will throw `ORA01790`.
Maybe casting this numbers will be the solution for you: `select cast(1 as varchar2(5)) from dual union select 'a' from dual`.

Comment: thanks +ponder .. that really helped.. previously there was a way to mark someone's answer as a right answer.. now i am only able to make ur answer as up by one there is no option to mark is right one :/